# recoding variable into two new variables in R

Tags: r

I have a variable A containing continuous numeric values and a binary variable B. I would like to create a new variable A1 which contains the same values as A if B=1 and missing values (NA) if B=2.
Many thanks!

Comment: Please can you show some example data and results?

Comment: Folks - lets be gentle with new users to SO (i.e. the -1's). This question is quite clear even though evidence of previous attempts is lacking.

Comment: Besides `ifelse`, I guess you could also just index `A` through `B`, i.e. `A[B == 2] <- NA`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ifelse()` for that:

```
a1 <- ifelse(B == 1, A, NA)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ifelse` for this:

```
A = runif(100)
B = sample(c(0,1), 100, replace = TRUE)
B1 = ifelse(B == 1, A, NA)
```

You can even leave out the `== 1` as R interprets `0` as `FALSE` and any other number as `TRUE`:

```
B1 = ifelse(B, A, NA)
```

Although the `== 1` is both more flexible and makes it more clear what happens. So I'd go for the first approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple and efficient approach **without `ifelse`**:

```
A <- 1:10
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
B <- rep(1:2, 5)
# [1] 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
A1 <- A * NA ^ (B - 1)
# [1]  1 NA  3 NA  5 NA  7 NA  9 NA
```